# Selectize autocomplete triggering postback when backspace button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, selectize.js

I am using [Selectize.js](https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/) in my ASP.NET WebForms project. I am converting an ASP.NET Server Side DropDown to autocomplete dropdown using this plugin. The dropdown's text and value are bound to a DataSet and triggers a postback when an item is selected, which redirects the page to another page. Everything is working fine except when I press the backspace button while searching the item inside Selectize autocomplete, it removes the previous text completely and redirects to the page with the last selected dropdown option. Following is the code:

ASP.NET Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClients" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged"
                AutoPostBack="true" Font-Size="Larger" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a hospital...">
```

Selectize Initiailization:

```
$('#<%=ddlClients.ClientID %>').selectize({
                allowEmptyOption: true,
                sortField: 'text',
                searchField: 'text',
                valueField: 'value'
            });
```

Comment: Can you please tell me if you tried the answer?

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the backspace issue.  (I fixed my code.)

In your RouteConfig.cs

```
//routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();

var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off; // RedirectMode.Permanent
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

In your Shiva2.aspx

```
<%@ Page ClientIDMode="Static" Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Shiva2.aspx.cs" Inherits="FredWebForm.Shiva2" %>

<%--!!!Need the ClientIDMode above  ClientIDMode="Static"--%>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Tags-Input-Select-Box-selectize-js/selectize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Custom-Tags-Input-Select-Box-selectize-js/examples/_stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.6.14/selectize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Shiva2.aspx/GetData",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#<%=selectbeast.ClientID %>').empty();
                    $.each(JSON.parse(result.d), function (i, anObj) {
                        $('#<%=selectbeast.ClientID %>').append($('<option>').text(anObj.Text).attr('value', anObj.Value));
                    });
                    $('#selectbeast').val("");
                    $('#selectbeast').selectize({
                        allowEmptyOption: true,
                        sortField: 'text',
                        searchField: 'text',
                        valueField: 'value'
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr, status) {
                    alert("An error occurred: " + status);
                }
            });
            $('#<%=selectbeast.ClientID %>').change(function () {
                //this gets called twice the way the library was written

                //user made a selection
                if ($('#<%=selectbeast.ClientID %>').val() != "0" && $('#<%=selectbeast.ClientID %>').val() != "") {
                    //there is only one form in webforms
                    document.forms[0].submit();
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
    <div class="demo">
        <%--I could not use asp:DropDownList because autopost repeated posts--%>
        <select runat="server" id="selectbeast" class="demo-default" placeholder="Select a hospital..." />
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Shiva2.aspx.cs

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace FredWebForm
{
    public class SelectListItem
    {
        public SelectListItem(string text, string value)
        {
            Text = text;
            Value = value;
                       }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
         }

    public partial class Shiva2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem("", ""));
            items.Add(new SelectListItem("Abrazio", "1"));
            items.Add(new SelectListItem("Humana", "2"));
            items.Add(new SelectListItem("Good Samaritan", "3"));
            //GET NewtonSoft JSON
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var passParmValue = Request.Form["ctl00$MainContent$selectbeast"]; 
            //var passParmValue = selectbeast.Value;
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(passParmValue))
            {
                Server.Transfer("~/Shiva3.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Shiva3.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Shiva3.aspx.cs" Inherits="FredWebForm.Shiva3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    My other Page
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I will try your solution again once I shift back to selectize. Due to urgency, I shifted back to simple drop-down. I will work on your solution this week and let you know.